# How do I read comma separated values from a .txt file in MATLAB using textscan()?

Tags: matlab, csv, textscan

I have a .txt file with rows consisting of three elements, a word and two numbers, separated by commas.

For example:

```
a,142,5
aa,3,0
abb,5,0
ability,3,0
about,2,0
```

I want to read the file and put the words in one variable, the first numbers in another, and the second numbers in another but I am having trouble with `textscan`.

This is what I have so far:

```
File = [LOCAL_DIR 'filetoread.txt'];
FID_File = fopen(File,'r');
[words,var1,var2] = textscan(File,'%s %f %f','Delimiter',',');
fclose(FID_File);
```

I can't seem to figure out how to use a delimiter with `textscan`.

Comment: If you're reading a file, then the first argument to `textscan` needs to be a file ID created with [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html). Also, your output arguments are invalid. Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I forgot to use fopen(), I edited the post to include it. Still having the same problem though. Horchler, What is meant by "your output arguments are invalid" ?

Comment: See the answer by @rayryeng below and read the documentation. There is no form of `textscan` that supports more than two output arguments.

Comment: Got it. I didn't see his answer when I posted that last comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

horchler is indeed correct.  You first need to open up the file with [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) which provides a file ID / pointer to the actual file.  You'd then use this with [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).  Also, you really only need one output variable because each "column" will be placed as a separate column in a cell array once you use `textscan`.  You also need to specify the delimiter to be the `,` character because that's what is being used to separate between columns.  This is done by using the `Delimiter` option in `textscan` and you specify the `,` character as the delimiter character.  You'd then close the file after you're done using [`fclose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html).

As such, you just do this:

```
File = [LOCAL_DIR 'filetoread.txt'];
f = fopen(File, 'r');
C = textscan(f, '%s%f%f', 'Delimiter', ',');
fclose(f);
```

Take note that the formatting string has no spaces because the delimiter flag will take care of that work.  Don't add any spaces.  `C` will contain a cell array of columns.  Now if you want to split up the columns into separate variables, just access the right cells:

```
names = C{1};
num1 = C{2};
num2 = C{3};
```

These are what the variables look like now by putting the text you provided in your post to a file called `filetoread.txt`:

```
>> names

names = 

    'a'
    'aa'
    'abb'
    'ability'
    'about'

>> num1

num1 =

   142
     3
     5
     3
     2

>> num2

num2 =

     5
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

Take note that `names` is a cell array of names, so accessing the right name is done by simply doing `n = names{ii};` where `ii` is the name you want to access.  You'd access the values in the other two variables using the normal indexing notation (i.e. `n = num1(ii);` or `n = num2(ii);`).

Comment: Thanks. This seems like it is what I am looking for. I am running into the problem though that using this I end up with an "Empty cell array". Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3716193 Did you use the code exactly as I put it above?  Make sure **there are no spaces** in the formatting string (i.e. `%s%f%f` as opposed to `%s %f %f`).

Comment: My mistake, somehow my .txt file was completely blank which is why I was getting an empty cell array. Thanks for the help, this worked.

Comment: @user3716193 oops!  No worries. Glad I could help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For splitting the data/labels that are separated with "," (comma) is shown below with an example.

a="PV_1,SHP_1,BATTERY_1,B_1"

sepColumns = strsplit(temp, [","])

Ans:

sepColumns =

1×4 string array

```
"PV_LOCATION"    "SHP_LOCATION"    "BATTERY_LOCATION"    "BATTERY_SIZE_KW"
```